# "defineCall is not a function". Using sequelize with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm learning how to use Sequelize for a Node.JS project, I'm working on the models:

index.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://bf3a13a7df5b2f:e2707ede@us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net/heroku_6bdb0d8ad6c6a50?reconnect=true');

// load models
var models = [
  'student',
   ];

models.forEach(function(model) {
  module.exports[model] = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/' + model);
});

// export connection
module.exports.student= student;
module.exports.sequelize = sequelize;
```

student.js

```
var sequelize = require('./dbConnection');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const student = sequelize.define('student', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  middleName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  dob: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },

  //student.sync({force: true});
});

module.exports = student;
```

and this is the error message I receive from the command line:

```
C:\Users\adria\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\ScholarMean1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:691
    this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
                             ^

TypeError: defineCall is not a function
```

I managed to make it work if the model is in index.js, but because I want to make a file for each model I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

I saw a similar problem just now and the problem was a file that was in the `models` folder that was not actually a database model. Ensure that your `models` folder only contains models for your database. Hopefully this helps!